# How to write for loop for executing a piece of code in case of exception in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop

I have a mapper code that

```
 Dim packet As A = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj)
```

My architect suggested that, sometimes the properties are initialized a bit late or maybe the values are likely to get mapped even before the properties are initialized.

So he asked me to write a for or while loop and configure that loop value in web.config file and execute the function/loop that many times so that if it fails for say 1st time, then we try to execute and if it fails again then we execute again and say I put the value as 5 in config file, it executes for 5 times and in the 5th time also it fails, then catch that mapper exception he said.

**UPDATE**

Tried this,

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 5
Dim packet As A = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj)
NEXT
```

Comment: Do you need help reading from the config file, or writing a for loop in vb.net using what you've read from the config file?

Comment: @charliefox2: I can read from config file. Also I wrote a for loop now, but I feel it executes 5 times irrespective of successful mapping first time itself. I want to call or execute the loop ONLY if it is an exception. Let me put the updated code above. Please help

Comment: Can you put an If statement within the for loop checking to see if the mapping was successful?

Something like `If successful Then Exit For`

Comment: Hi @Deevinee This is the second time you've tagged a `VB.Net` question with `C#` - they're different languages..:)

Comment: @charliefox2: I am trying, dont know how to check if its successful. Should I keep some boolean value?

Comment: @Rob: Today forst day in VB.NET for me. But if I can write in C#, I can convert :P

Comment: I updated my answer, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

Your code as shown below:

```
Dim loopValue As Integer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LoopValue")
Dim isSuccessful As Boolean = False 

For index As Integer = 1 To loopValue 
    If isSuccessful Then Exit For Else packet = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj) 
    isSuccessful = True 
Next
```

Will set `isSuccessful` to `True` right after it tries to map the first time. You need an if statement to determine whether or not `packet` mapped properly. I don't have any experience with mapping, so I can't be of much help there. You might try `If packet != null Then isSuccessful = True`, but I can't be certain.

**Edit:**

If the mapping is not successful, then packet should equal nothing, right?

`If packet = nothing Then packet As A = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj) Else Exit For`

Just define packet outside of the for loop.

---

Maybe something like this:

```
For index As Integer = 1 To configVar 
    'configVar is the integer read from the config file
    If successful Then Exit For Else Dim packet As A = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj) 
    'successful, in this case is some test to determine whether or not the mapping was successful
Next
```

I'm not too familiar with mappings like the question you posed, but this should work for you.

Comment: thank you so much, Successful" is a keyword in VB.net? Sorry I am first day in VB

Comment: I just made up `successful`. It's a placeholder for whatever you would use to determine if your mapping was successful... like a function, maybe. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: ok this is what I did now based on your inputs, but I am afraid about the conversion when I read from config file. Is it integer by default?

Comment: <add key="LoopValue" value="5" />

Comment: Dim loopValue As Integer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LoopValue").ToString()
                For index As Integer = 1 To loopValue
                    If successful Then Exit For Else 
                    packet = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj)
                Next

Comment: `Dim configVar as Integer = x` Of course, instead of x, you'd have the config value from the config file.

Comment: Oh successful throw error. How should I check if its successful? Should I keep some bool variable and make it true if successful?

Comment: This is the final code. Is this correct?                 Dim loopValue As Integer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LoopValue").ToString()
                Dim isSuccessful As Boolean = False
                For index As Integer = 1 To loopValue
                    If isSuccessful Then Exit For Else 
                    packet = Mapper.Map(Of B)(myObj)
                    isSuccessful = True
                Next

Comment: I think your valuable guidance helped me. But I tweaked like above and looks good, but please confirm me. ???

Comment: @Deevinee I updated my answer (again). Unfortunately, I don't know much about mapping, but hopefully that points you in the right direction?

Comment: @charlieo thanks but one quick question, it's an integer but I think I don't remember exactly how I gave in the configuration file I mean whether the value with quotation mark or Without quotation as I'm out of office already as I work in Australia. Tomorrow morning I will check.Now if it's without quotation, then it would be an integer and even otherwise we declare variable loopValue as integer. Why you do tostring?

Comment: Sorry, didn't even notice the ToString(). That's used to convert the object in question to a string, but we _don't_ want that. Edited my answer to remove that.